# Migrate existing VS 2010 web project to VS 2012

Tags: migration, visual-studio-2012

I have an existing Visual Studio 2010 web project that I want to migrate to Visual Studio 2012. Can anybody suggest steps on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your solution with VS2012, it's compatible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx